# Getting FormatException response from my flutter api response

Tags: flutter

I have a button which when clicked, prints out response.

This is how the response is

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "user": "Worked well"
}
```

when I test it with postman it works fine, but when I try it from my flutter project, I get this error

```
I/flutter ( 5147): Response: - Instance of 'Response'
I/flutter ( 5147): FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
I/flutter ( 5147): <!DOCTYPE html>
I/flutter ( 5147): ^
```

This is my flutter code:

```
  http.Response response = await http.post(
    Uri.parse(url + 'testMe.php'),
    headers: headers,
    body: body,
  );
  print('response ${response}');
  if (response.body.isNotEmpty) {
    json.decode(json.encode(response.body));
  } else {
    print('Response is empty...');
  }
```

One thing I noticed is that, sometimes it does not throw the error above in flutter, it works fine and sometimes it throws the error, so I don't why it happen that way.

Flu[image: tter Header]

Postman Header[image]

Comment: why are you using `json.decode(json.encode(response.body));` it should be `json.decode(response.body);`

Comment: Looks like you are getting html back instead of json . Try printing response.body

Comment: @GrahamD I got a 503 response after printing the status code, what can I do about that, because it works fine on postman?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
Map<String, String> headers = {
 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
 'Charset': 'utf-8',
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your api return you a `html` instead of `json`, you can do this to avoid getting `FormatException`:

```
http.Response response = await http.post(
  Uri.parse(url + 'testMe.php'),
  headers: headers,
  body: body,
);

print('response ${response}');
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  json.decode(response.body);
} else {
  print('Response is empty...');
}
```

usually when statuscode is 500 or 404 this happened, when you check for status code 200, you can avoid getting this `FormatException`.

Also you don't need to encode the response and decode it again, your response is already encoded in server side, just decode it.

Comment: I got a 503 response after printing the status code, what can I do about that, because it works fine on postman?

Comment: that is a server issue, you can't do anything about it, you can just handle exception and show some message to user.

Comment: can you show me the headers of your postman? also your headers in app.

Comment: I have updated my question above with the header